# Search for people by name in FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to develop a search for people by name feature using the Facebook API.

I'm trying this FQL query:

```
SELECT uid, username, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE strpos(name, 'Alfredo Artiles') >= 0
```

But I get an "**Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column.**" error.

I also tried to add a "and uid > 0" condition, but that didn't work too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**later edit**

Ok, sorry for the mistake regarding strpos, I didn't remeber it existence last time i checked the fql docs. The thing about it is that it can be used just in certain cases. You need to have a primar indexable column in your where clause and a second condition with strpos (at least this is how I succeded using it). For example:

```
SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND strpos(message, 'stuff') > 0 limit 50
```

I hope this clarifies a little bit the confusion with this function.

Comment: FQL has now(), strlen(), substr() and strpos() check it here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: Your query returns only exact matchs

Comment: sorry for the mistake with strpos, please recheck my answer to see what i edited

Comment: What you says seems to make sense but doesn't help me. Is there any way to make a fulltext search using FQL?

Comment: fulltext search? Like mysql fulltext? No, it is not possible.

Comment: For case-insensitive search, use `strpos(lower(name), "input") >=0` and make sure you lower-case your input.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT uid, username, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE contains('Alfredo Artiles')
```

I have no idea why it works, as it violates the "at least and indexable field in WHERE", but it does.

EDIT: this is where I read it: [link](http://www.fbrell.com/hidden/whitepages)

Comment: How did you reach the link you shared? also do you know what 'contains' function does here? and which field/fields is searches?

Comment: Sorry but I am not working on that project since long time and I don't remember. Probably I just googled

Answer (score 0):

U need to specify the uid in where clause fetch details in facebook user table. we don't get the the all user details.here get the details of currently logged in user

```
"SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM 
friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND strpos(name,'Alfredo Artiles') >=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

YES, YOU CAN!!!

Try to search in profile table, instead of user table. In profile table, the name field is indexable, so your statement would have to change only a bit:

```
SELECT id, username, name, pic_square FROM profile WHERE contains('alfredo artiles') and type='user'
```

Contains is not case-sensitive while strpos is. You could still use lower and strpos, but you would also have the problem of special characters. Contains is the solution.

You can find all fields of profile table in [facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile):

Hope it helps!